# django-tagging only show tags from filtered items

Tags: django, django-templates, django-apps, django-tagging

I was wondering how you can filter an object in django-tagging.

For instance if you have written an article and the status is still `draft` you obviously don't want to show these before the article has been pushed to a live status.

Do you do it in the `{% tags_for_model products.Widget as widget_tags %}` or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by using usage_for_model in your view you can add filters e.g.

```
Tag.objects.usage_for_model(ModelClass, filters={"status":1})
```

or create a version of tags_for_model that accepts filters

Answer (score 1):

You don't filter the objects from which retrieve tags on the templatetags.
I did not find a straight forward way to have tags for

```
Product.objects.filter(draft= False)
```

What I would do is to create a proxy model of Product like PublishedProduct

```
class PublishedProduct(Product):
    objects = PublishedProductManager()
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

and then set its default manager to return the subset from the filter (e.g. filter(draft= False))

```
class PublishedProduct(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(PublishedProduct, self).get_query_set().filter(draft= False)
```